# Trying to add SSL certificate to my site but getting an error

Tags: security, nginx, ssl

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) to add SSL certificates to my site, however it returns this error: `Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA`.

At the moment this method [does not work for the time-being due to a security flaw, so here is the alternate method](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solution-client-with-the-currently-selected-authenticator-does-not-support-any-combination-of-challenges-that-will-satisfy-the-ca/49983).

I'm trying to implement the alternate code-paste: `sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path <path to served directory> --installer nginx -d <domain>` however am not sure what to put in `<path to served directory>`.

Is the "path to served directory" the nginx config? Would it look something like this: `etc/nginx/sites-available/<projectname>`?

Comment: SSH and SSL are not the same thing. Please take a little more time to write questions. I advise using paragraphs in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Inside that file, `/etc/nginx/sites-available/<projectname>` you have a "server" block, and inside that block you have a "root" statement:

```
server {
    ....
    root <pathname>;
    ....
}
```

That pathname is the "path to the server directory"; `certbot` will place something there to be served by your `nginx` server as evidence that it does indeed serve the domain to be certified.