# "Failed authorization procedure" when trying to add SSL certificates to site

Tags: ssh, security, nginx

Following on from [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417442/trying-to-add-ssl-certificate-to-my-site-but-getting-an-error), when I ran this command in my digital ocean server:

```
sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path /home/james/postr --installer nginx -d <sitename>
```

I get this error:

```
Failed authorization procedure

The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from 
http://www.<sitename>.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oAVGa4eBNfQQ1Vrn_q-
iKjV2T6ue3H5kOcxEWpztrHc

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.venvor.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.<sitename>.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/oAVGa4eBNfQQ1Vrn_q-
   iKjV2T6ue3H5kOcxEWpztrHc:
   "<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL
   /.well-known/acme-challenge/oAVGa4eBNfQQ1Vrn_q-iKjV2T6ue3H5kOcxEWpztrHc
   was not found on "
```

I already tried adding the url path to my urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^.well-known/acme-challenge/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

However it still doesn't work. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Please read my comments and changes to your last question.

Comment: My mistake, I assume the edit fixed it? Do you have any idea about my error?